# Assigning weights to a multilabel SVM to balance classes

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

How is this done? I am using Sklearn to train an SVM. My classes are unbalanced. Note that my problem is multiclass, multilabel so I am using `OneVsRestClassifier`:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='rbf'))
clf = clf.fit(x, y) 
pred = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Can I add a 'sample_weight' parameter somewhere to account for the unbalanced classes? If I add a class_weight dict to the svm I get the error:

> ValueError: Class label 2 not present

This is because I have converted my labels to binary using the mlb. However, if I do not convert the labels to binary, I get:

> ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead.

`class_weight` is a `dict`, mapping the class labels to the weight: `{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3...}`

Here are the details of x and y:

```
print(X[0])  
[ 0.76625633  0.63062721  0.01954162 ...,  1.1767817   0.249034    0.23544988]
print(type(X))
'numpy.ndarray'

print(y[0])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  # before binary conversion

print(type(y))
'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: If you are just asking for Python code, that would be off topic here. But I think your 'how to assign weights to balance classes' is more general & software-neutral. That can be answered here, & you may be able to figure out the code to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is related to this [other one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/libsvm-cost-weights-for-unbalanced-data-doesnt-work/47980#47980) where a principled way of dealing with this problem is given.

Another possibility that I can think of is to generate data that is contained within the convex hull of each class (since in the case of separable classes, the separating hyperplane bisects the shortest vector joining the convex hulls of each class).