# How can I interpret the following learning curves?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, supervised-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am training a SVM with linear kernel over a training set of 3759 elements. The dimension of my problem is 2055, in other words, each example belonged to my training set is described by 2055 features. When I plot the learning curves, I got the curves of the figure. How can I interpret this image and evaluate my model? I really consider that obtaining a very high precision in the testing set at the very beginning is not usual.

[image: Learning Curve SVM]

Average of 30 runs

[image: Confusion matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your problem is relatively simple, so your SVM converges to a good solution really fast.

However if your dataset is highly skewed, then simply a high precision might be misleading. For example, if you are doing a spam email classification and 95% of your training data is 0 (or non-spam), then a classifier always prediction 0 will give you 95% accuracy.

You may want to look at the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) of your model output to see whether it is such a case. If it is, you may consider to upsample the minority class(es) or to assign different weights to your classes ( see some discussions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/libsvm-cost-weights-for-unbalanced-data-doesnt-work)).

Comment: this is the confusion matrix, I see it quite well?

Comment: Yes @WilberConcepciónLugo, it seems quite well.

Comment: you know, I just realized that it's not balanced (1340, 2419), I'll try again when I swing it... thank you so much

Comment: balance the data and everything remains the same